# How many hours of labor needed for this kind of body work?

Tags: body-work

My 2011 Toyota Corolla needs the following body and mechanical work:

- Front bumper replacement
- Front left fender and fender liner replacement
- Front left door handle replacement
- Replacement of the following suspension components: front left struts, front left lower control arm, front left knuckle
- Front left wheel and tire replacement

How many hours of labor reasonably needed for the above repair?

Edit: I am not doing the repair myself, but have to send it to a body shop. However, I don't want to be fooled by the hours quoted by them if it's unreasonably high. The car met an accident last month, but the condition is not too bad. The body shop has let me know that the above-mentioned repair/replacements are needed. The final quote which should include labor, too, is pending yet.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Was the car in accident or is this just repairs because the car is older? If it was an accident, its hard to say how many hours a thing takes to repair because we can't see the damage. For example the mounts where the front bumper or fenders mount on could be damaged as well, making it take more time than just simply replacing it.

Comment: What kind of workshop access and specialist tools are available?  Do you have air tools?  Do you have a ramp?  Do you have spring compressors?  It's a very difficult question to answer.  Do you mean yourself doing the repair?  How much mechanical experience do you have?  Can you get an assistant for part of the job?

Comment: @SteveMatthews - I think the OP is looking for a rough estimate in book hours for the repair.

Comment: I have updated the original question with some clarification.